# How to combine two dataframe value using weighted average in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframe.

There is a dataframe(df1) in which users rate each item and a dataframe(df2) in which similarity between other users and targets is calculated.

I want to predict the target user's rating(result_df) using df1,df2.

[image]

[image]

```
df1 <- data.frame('user'=c('user1', 'user2', 'user3'),
          'item1'=c(NA,2,3),
          'item2'=c(1,5,NA),
          'item3'=c(1,5,5))

df2 <- data.frame('user'=c('user1', 'user2', 'user3'),
          'ratio'=c(0.9,0.3,0.5))
```

The method is to calculate a weighted average according to the similarity for users whose rating is not na for each item.

For example, the method of calculating the predicted score of item1 is as follows.

1. Change the similarity(ratio) between user2 and user3, not NA value, so that the sum becomes 1.

user2 ratio: 0.3 -> 0.375
user3 ratio: 0.5 -> 0.625

2. Calculate the weighted average of user2 and user3.

2 * 0.375+3 * 0.625 = 2.625

3. For item2 : 1 * 0.75 + 5 * 0.25 = 2

   For item3 : 1 * 9/17 + 5 * 3/17 + 5 * 5/17 = 2.555..

I want to make result_df like this, is there a function that can do this calculation at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the calculation for each column using `sapply` :

```
sapply(df1[-1], function(x) sum(na.omit(x) * prop.table(df2$ratio[!is.na(x)])))

#   item1    item2    item3 
#2.625000 2.000000 2.882353
```

Comment: Again, you gave me the right answer! perfect! thanks!!!